# ECS EC2: How to run 1 task per instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I was using ECS Fargate in this way: job arrives -> lambda creates a new task -> Fargate container runs the job -> job finishes -> lambda stop the task

Now, I am migrating from Fargate to ECS EC2 due to its swap feature. I would like to use the same workflow. I believe it could be like this: job arrives -> lambda creates a new EC2 instance running the docker image -> container runs the job -> job finishes -> lambda stop the EC2 instance.

How should I make Ecs create a Ecs-registered Ec2 running my new task when the job arrives.

Comment: Yes, it is achievable. What exactly is your issue? Just want to know "Is this achievable with ECS EC2?"? Or you have more specific problem than that?

Comment: Looks like all the task will go to the instance that is registered into Ecs cluster. I didn't find a way to create the instance and run the new job in this instance when the job arrives

Answer (score 0):

When you run your tasks, you can specify [Task placement constraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html). I think for marking specific instance you would have to use [custom attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html), as there is no direct selection of instances based on instance-id.

Comment: Should I create this new instance and register it into the Ecs cluster both on my own? Cuz I would like to have #instances = #jobs

Comment: @EzyHoo That's why I ask. Your question is so generic than anyone can only provide generic answer. Yes, you can orchestrate everything yourself, or you can setup autoscaling groups for the instances to be added automatically if needed. Eitherway, you require custom solution. Easiest would be just to stick with Fargate.

Comment: What  about deploying the task using the daemon service scheduler strategy? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html